# Create nested JSON with minimal-json?

Tags: java, json, nested

I'm using [minimal-json](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/) ([github](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json)) and am trying to create a nested JSON like so:

```
String jsonInner = new JsonObject().add("Inner", "i").toString();
String jsonMiddle = new JsonObject().add("Middle", jsonInner).toString();
String jsonOuter = new JsonObject().add("Outer", jsonMiddle).toString();
```

In my debug console, the result looks like this:

```
{"Outer":"{\"Middle\":\"{\\\"Inner\\\":\\\"i\\\"}\"}"}
```

Not quite what I was expecting; there is a bit much escaping going on...
I'm a bit slow today; can anyone please point out how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
JsonValue inner = new JsonObject().add("Inner", "i");
JsonValue middle = new JsonObject().add("Middle", inner);
String outerAsString = new JsonObjec().add("Outer", middle).toString();
```

?

The problem is that you add a serialized JSON as a String in `middle` and `outer`; this is not what you want.

Comment: Ouch; you're right of course. `JsonObject i = new JsonObject()...` would work as well... I never considered it, as my IDE's code completion didn't offer it. It only suggested `add(String, JsonValue)`, and I failed to realise that `JsonObject extends JsonValue` (and that JsonValue can hold more than an atomic value)... Time for a break, I guess... :)

Comment: Thanks! Solved the issue